# Python - "'int' object is not subscriptable" on list object

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm trying to create a function, using functional programming, which receives a number and a list of numbers as arguments and returns the number of times the number occurs in the list. And I can't for the life of me figure out why I get this error. I have browsed similar questions but I can't understand what is wrong.

Here is the code:

```
def count(num, list):
    if list == []:
        return 0
    elif list[0] == num:    # I am getting the error on this line
        return 1 + count(list[1:], num)
    else:
        return 0 + count(list[1:], num)

print (count(4, []))
print (count(3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
print (count(1, [1, 1, 1]))
```

Comment: you should probably change the first if to "not list" instead of == []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num` should be the first parameter

```
def count(num, list):
    if list == []:
        return 0
    elif list[0] == num:
        return 1 + count(num, list[1:]) # <- here 
    else:
        return 0 + count(num, list[1:]) # <- and here
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't even notice that. Looking at the same code for a while makes you blind apparently. Thanks! :)